# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. - laravel passport

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-passport

```laravel
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**Problem:**

> ```
>  - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.6
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.5
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.4
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.3
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.2
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.1
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.0
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport 6.0.x-dev
>     - Conclusion: remove paragonie/random_compat v9.99.9
> ```
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: In the error it should also say why it wasn't able to install the package...are you able to add that part of the error to your questions as well.

Comment: I have the same issue - stock standard Laravel composer.json. Researching .....

Comment: See here, worked for me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51475248/composer-unable-to-install-laravel-passport

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composer unable to install laravel/passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51475248/composer-unable-to-install-laravel-passport)