# composer unable to install laravel/passport

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-passport

I have created a new project with

```
laravel new blogposts
```

using "Laravel Installer 2.0.1" globally installed on my ubuntu 18.

When i trying to install passport using

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

following errors are their

```
Using version ^6.0 for laravel/passport
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.  

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.6

- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport v6.0.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/passport 6.0.x-dev
- Conclusion: remove paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
- Installation request for laravel/passport ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[6.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.0.5, v6.0.6].
- Conclusion: don't install paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
- laravel/passport 6.0.x-dev requires league/oauth2-server ^7.0 -> satisfiable by league/oauth2-server[7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.2.0].
- league/oauth2-server 7.1.0 requires defuse/php-encryption ^2.1 -> satisfiable by defuse/php-encryption[v2.1.0, v2.2.0].
- league/oauth2-server 7.1.1 requires defuse/php-encryption ^2.1 -> satisfiable by defuse/php-encryption[v2.1.0, v2.2.0].
- league/oauth2-server 7.2.0 requires defuse/php-encryption ^2.1 -> satisfiable by defuse/php-encryption[v2.1.0, v2.2.0].
- league/oauth2-server 7.0.0 requires paragonie/random_compat ^2.0 -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9].
- defuse/php-encryption v2.1.0 requires paragonie/random_compat ~2.0 -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9].
- defuse/php-encryption v2.2.0 requires paragonie/random_compat ~2.0 -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.0, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.1, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.10, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.11, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.12, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.13, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.14, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.15, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.16, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.17, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.2, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.3, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.4, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.5, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.6, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.7, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.8, v9.99.99].
- Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.9, v9.99.99].
- Installation request for paragonie/random_compat (locked at v9.99.99) -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v9.99.99].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try: composer require laravel/passport "4.0.*" and let me know if not works

Comment: @Rajinder i tired with command by you, but still not installed,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This link may help you https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/774

They said, it fixed their issue

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:2.*
composer require laravel/passport
```

Answer (score 19):

I am using PHP8.0 and face the same issue running the command and it's worked for me.

```
composer require laravel/passport  --with-all-dependencies
```

Answer (score 8):

Same issue with Laravel 5.5.40 or higher. So you need to specify the version of the passport like this;

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:2.*
composer require laravel/passport=~4.0
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. Laravel 5.7. The best passport version I was able to get was 5.0 though. Right now it's on v8.4.1, so I'm upgrading Laravel for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this! It worked for me

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:2.*
composer require laravel/passport=~4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your composer.json file, remove the version

You need to set it to:

```
{
    "require": {
        "rackspace/php-opencloud": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your composer.json file

And set below :

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/passport": "~4.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    },
```

And then run `composer update` command.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment since I do not have 50 Rep but I would like to add onto rkj's solution. Those commands do work but in my case I was running laravel through homestead and you cannot fetch those packages while sshing into homestead you must use your global composer to fetch the packages. This is a windows 10 machine also to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

simply install any lower version of passport, Run the command:

composer require laravel/passport "5.*"

Answer (score 0):

> I was getting same error in laravel 10 and php 8.2 when i try to install laravel passport fot API
> **Solution**:
> just use below command this will work for you

```
composer require laravel/passport  --with-all-dependencies
```

this worked for me in installing laravel passport I hope this will work for you too.